# MySQL: count votes for users

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a way to count votes for a user in a MySQL database.

**Tables and Columns:**

```
companion
 - companion_id
 - news_id
 - user_id
news
 - news_id
 - user_id
user
 - user_id
 - user_name
vote
 - vote_id
 - news_id
 - user_id
```

check out the **[SQL Fiddle Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/841d9f/14)**

**Conditions:**

- every *user* can have several *news*
- every *news* can have several *votes*
- every *news* can have several *companions* (companions are user)
- every *user* can vote for several *news* (not important for this query)

**Target:**

Now I'm trying to figure out how many votes a user has together: on his own news an on which he is linked as a companion. The solution should be a **single** MySQL query.

**Example for *User2*:**

- *User2* has **1** news article. This news article has **2** votes.
- *User2* is companion of **1** article. This news article has **3** votes.
- *User2* should have **5** votes

**Approach:**

The following query results 31 and not 5, because it can't group it correct over 2 differnt tables.

```
SELECT   u.user_name,
         u.user_id,
         COUNT(v.vote_id) AS votes
FROM     user u,
         news n,
         companion c,
         vote v
WHERE    u.user_id = 2 AND
         (
           (
             u.user_id = n.user_id AND
             n.news_id = v.news_id
           ) OR
           (
              u.user_id = c.user_id AND
              c.news_id = v.news_id
           )
         )
GROUP BY u.user_id
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not joining, unioning is the key. Note, that you have to change the user_id twice. Feel free to join users table to get real user names.

See it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/841d9f/66).

```
SELECT   u.user_name, 
         count(*)
FROM
(
         SELECT news_id,
                user_id
         FROM   news
         WHERE  user_id = 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT news_id,
                user_id
         FROM   companion
         WHERE  user_id = 2
)        sq
JOIN     vote v 
ON       v.news_id = sq.news_id
JOIN     user u
ON       sq.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY sq.user_id;
```